# How to print SQLAlchemy update query?

Tags: python, debugging, sqlalchemy

According to [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) printing queries is as simple as print(query).

But according to `update` function description, it returns an integer

*:return: the count of rows matched as returned by the database's
"row count" feature.*

My code:

```py
    state = 'router_in_use'
   
    q = self.db_session.query(Router).filter(
        Router.id == self.router_id,
    ).update(
        {Router.state: state}, synchronize_session=False
    )

    #print(q) outputs just 1

    self.db_session.commit()
```

Is there a way to print `q` query in SQL language?

Query itself works fine.

python 3.8

Comment: If its just for debugging you can add `echo=True` to `create_engine`

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks. But there are a lot of queries. I'd prefer to print this one only @flakes

Comment: Have you tried this `print(str(query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})))`?

Comment: print(q.statement) gives an error: 'int' object has no attribute 'statement' @CharlesHan